# WebStorm breakpoint opens served file

Tags: debugging, webstorm, breakpoints

I have an `app.js` file located in `client/js/app.js`

Here's a snippet of the file describing a state:

```
  .state('loginworkflow', {
    url:'/loginworkflow/:workflowId',
    templateUrl: 'views/templates/response.view.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams, LoginResponseService) {
      $scope.results = LoginResponseService.findById($stateParams.workflowId);
    }
  })
```

However whenever I put a breakpoint in the controller function instead of opening the `client/js/app.js` file and breaking on the line it instead opens a new editor window `localhost:3000/js/app.js` and breaks on the line specified in the original file.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's as if WebStorm doesn't realise that the `app.js` file is located on the local file system?

I've searched around but I can't find where to map local files.

Comment: If IDE does things like this then you could use [Remote Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/debugging-javascript.html?search=debug#d275199e534) where you can specify mapping between URL and actual file (no need to do on per-file basis -- mapping gets inherited from higher/folder level). This is not required for local debugging .. but since it behaves like this (for whatever reason) .. then this solution should help.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me LazyOne but I am Remote Debugging... that's the problem alas.

Comment: did you try mapping 'client' directory to 'localhost:3000' in your JavaScript Debug run configuration? See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver

Comment: Hi Lena!! That was exactly the answer?? how do I flag that as the answer here?

Comment: Hi Lena, sorry to bother again but I'm getting the same problem in Intellij. I execute the frontend in Debug mode but stacktracess that arise have links to the served file e.g.

at Object.Question.question.save (http://localhost:8080/app/services/QuestionService.js:27:43)
    
I've mapped the url http://localhost:8080 to my local webapps directory which contains the app directory yet the IDE doesn't appear to marry them up?